# How to find the GCD of three numbers within a single method

Tags: java, int, greatest-common-divisor

I've got to ensure that the GCD between 3 numbers is no greater than 1.

Here's the code I have so far for the method:

```
private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
{
    for(int n = 0; n <= number; n++)
    {
        if()
    }

    return 1;
}
```

the `return 1` was already there when I started working on the lab. How can I make sure that the GCD is no more than 1? And return all three integers?

Here's the remainder of the code if it helps in figuring out what needs to be done:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Triples
{
 private int number;

public Triples()
{
    this(0);
}

public Triples(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

public void setNum(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
{
    for(int n = 0; n <= number; n++)
    {
        if()
    }

    return 1;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    int max = number;
    for(a = 1; a <= max; a++)
    {
        for(b = a +1; b <= max; b++)
        {
            for(c = b + 1; c <= max; c++)
            {
                if(Math.pow(a, 2)+ Math.pow(b, 2)== Math.pow(c, 2))
                {
                    if((a%2==1 && b%2==0)|| (a%2==0 && b%2==1))
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return output+"\n";
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my new coding for the same lab:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Triples
{
 private int number;

public Triples()
{
    this(0);
}

public Triples(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

public void setNum(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
{
    for(int n = 0; n <= number; n++)
    {
    int max = number;
    for(a = 1; a <= max; a++)
    {
        a = n;
        for(b = a +1; b <= max; b++)
        {
            b =n;
            for(c = b + 1; c <= max; c++)
            {
                c = n;
                if(Math.pow(a, 2)+ Math.pow(b, 2)== Math.pow(c, 2))
                {
                    if((a%2==1 && b%2==0)|| (a%2==0 && b%2==1))
                    {
                        if(a%2<=1 && b%2<=1 && c%2<=1)
                        {
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    return 1;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    output = greatestCommonFactor(a, b, c);


    return output+"\n";
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "return all three integers"?

Comment: int the line `private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)`

Comment: Here's a link to a google docs version of the lab sheet if it helps: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_ifaCiEZgtcX08tbW1jNThZZmM

Comment: I think this is what the question implies : You got to find the GCD of a, b and c. 1 is a 'default' because 1 is definitely a factor and the function should return an int. You got to write the code for determining the GCD and you code should be placed before 'return 1;'

Comment: @TJ-, isn't my code before the `return 1;` as it stands?

Comment: Does that do anything? Does it compile at all?

Comment: @TJ-, not yet, I've got all the other conditions that must be met for a Pythagorean triple to be true in my toString method and am just trying to figure out the getGCD method for now

Comment: Why do you want to put that in toString(). getGCD() should have the logic for determining the GCD. Isn't it? The organization of the code doesn't look correct.

Comment: I moved the code that is currently in the toString() just to temporarily relocate it until I got the GCD itself taken care of. Have you taken a look at the google docs file I listed in a comment above? Within the document is an "algorithm help" that I was basing my setup off of

Comment: There is now a new version of the code amended to the bottom of my OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) to calculate the GCD of `a` and `b`. Call the result `d`. Then the GCD of `a`, `b`, and `c` is the GCD of `c` and `d`; for that, you can use Euclid's algorithm again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force way if you don't care about efficiency:

```
private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
{
    limit = Math.min(a, b);
    limit = Math.min(limit, c);
    for(int n = limit; n >= 2; n--)
    {
        if ( (a % n == 0) && (b % n == 0) && (c % n == 0) ) {
            return n;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- You can save some work by only checking up to the minimum of `(a, b, c)`. Any number greater than that definitely won't be a GCD of all 3.
- You need to start your loop at `n = limit` instead of `n = 0` and count backwards.
- As soon as we come across a number that produces zero remainder for `(a, b, c)`, that must be the GCD.
- If nothing is found within the loop, GCD defaults to 1.

Comment: Because it is a homework problem, it's good if solutions are not shown before the student tries to solve the problem herself/himself.

Comment: still editing, noticing that I'm making lots of little mistakes on the sleep debt :<

Comment: I had to do a GCD lab a while back, but I don't have access to the completed file from home and remember doing the reverse counting but I couldn't think of how to implement it here

Comment: So I'm thinking that I could have it use the mod operator on each number it comes up for `n` with (referencing my code) and then if if say `n%2==1` then I could assign it to `a` but then I'm stuck on how to assign the other variables

Comment: an error in your solution is that a, b, and c are never assigned an actual value